# Find all entities using lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Person>` (people) every person has a `List<Kid>` (kids)

If I want to find all the kids, in LINQ this is what I would do

```
var kids=new List<Kids>();

foreach(var p in people)
{
    foreach(var kid in p.Kids)
    {
         kids.Add(kid);
    }
}
```

Is there a one line way of doing this using LINQ?

Comment: Are you trying to see if a "Kid" exists in "Kids"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's as simple as [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var kids = people.SelectMany(p => p.Kids);
```

(If you want a `List<Kid>` instead of an `IEnumerable<Kid>`, just call `.ToList()` on the result.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension method

```
var kids = new List(people.SelectMany(person => person.Kids));
```

Answer (score 3):

A "LINQ-non-lambda-style" version of `SelectMany`:

```
var allKids = 
  from p in people
  from k in p.Kids  // secondary "from" makes SelectMany (aka flat map)
  select k;

// Result from above is IEnumerable, to Force evaluation as a List:
List<Kid> allKidsList = allKids.ToList();
```